# syntax error when trying to include UserMailer into my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I'm trying to send an email if post = review but I am getting a syntax error.  How should the code be changed? Trying to add `UserMailer.review_email(@user).deliver` caused this error

This is the error that I'm getting

```
SyntaxError in PostsController#create  
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    mail(:to => admin@domain.com, :subject => "Review")
  syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
    mail(:to => admin@domain.com, :subject => "Review")
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

Here's the controller where I'm trying to place the UserMailer code

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      if @post.review
        UserMailer.review_email(@user).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Post will be reviewed"
      redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:success] = "Posted"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

user mailer model

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "account@domain.com"

  def review_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => admin@domain.com, :subject => "Post needs review")
  end

end
```

Comment: The error is likely in your mailer, which we cannot see.

Comment: just posted up the user mailer model.. let me know if you see anything off

Comment: Email addresses are strings. Also note that unless you have a filter or something you'll pass a `nil` for your `@user` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminate the (), and make the address a string.

```
mail :to => "admin@domain.com", :subject => "Post needs review"
```

Comment: I disagree with removing the `()`, particularly if keeping the old-style hash notation. It does nothing for readability and is inconsistent with the method definitions.

Comment: bbatsov's style guide says "Omit parentheses around parameters for methods that are part of an internal DSL (e.g. Rake, Rails, RSpec), methods that have "keyword" status in Ruby (e.g. attr_reader, puts) and attribute access methods. Use parentheses around the arguments of all other method invocations." That makes sense. I agree with Dave Newton, put the ()s back.